# Dynamics 365: Prevent firing plugin execution while updating record

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365, xrmtoolbox

I want to update a field without firing the plugin execution. I tried to update it with `SQL 4 CDS` from `Xrmtoolbox`, but the plugin executes and I get a timeout error. *This plugin is updating all child records*, but at this case we want to bypass this.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to update record without triggering plugins. At SQL 4 CDS, in Settings menu there is an option "Bypass custom plugins" as you can see at the screenshot below. By checking this option, you can update the record without triggering plugin execution

[image: Bypass custom plugins]

Answer (score 2):

In C# you can actually do this using an [`UpdateRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.updaterequest?view=dataverse-sdk-latest).

You would create the request like this:

```cs
var request = new UpdateRequest
{
    Target = entity,
    ["BypassCustomPluginExecution"] = true
};
```

> Important note: users must have the `prvBypassCustomPlugins` privilege to make this work. This privilege cannot be assigned through the UI and only the System Administrator role has this privilege by default.

See also [Bypass Custom Business Logic - MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/bypass-custom-business-logic).